# In Spring controller I'm getting previous date than actual date I'm sending

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, datepicker

I'm sending date from Date picker it's going correct date but when I check in the controller the date was getting yesterday date in spring boot backend and angualr js in frontend

I havea tried setting timezone in application properties
like :

> spring.jackson.time-zone=IST
>
> spring.jackson.locale=in_IN

but didn't work

date which is gonign ==dao: `Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time) and

the date which gets in controller== `dao=2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z`

Comment: Do you want to have your local date in controller side what you send from front-end?

Comment: date which is go from front end  = Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

JVM will take the default time zone as the server’s time zone. For example, if the server is running on IST, then the JVM takes the IST time as default.
You can use this code and initialize the time zone at server-side at the time of application start.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
// Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: NO still get prev day than actual date

Answer (score 0):

All-time objects that have associated TimeZone (java.util.Calendar etc) that Jackson constructs use the standard timezone (GMT), not the local time zone (whatever that might be). That is: Jackson defaults to using GMT for all processing unless specifically told otherwise.
Use this line in your JSON POJO class data member which is bind with data object coming from JSON.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="IST")
```

Comment: NO still get prev day than actual date